# get the location metadata of a video I choose in photoLibrary iOS objective-c

Tags: ios, location, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

I am selecting a video from the photo library using UIImagePickerController.  I have gotten the creation time and date of the video and I would like to get the location it was taken at.  I know that the videos taken on the iphone have the location as part of their metadata but I don't know how to access it.
Here is the code I used for the dat and time.

```
else if (picker.sourceType ==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
       
       NSURL * movieURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ;
        
       AVURLAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movieURL options:nil];

        PHAsset *theAsset = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ;
        
PHAsset *someAsset = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset];
        NSLog(@"someAsset%@",someAsset.location);
        self.currentLocation = someAsset.location;
            NSLog(@"creationDate1:%@",theAsset);
            NSLog(@"creationDate2:%@",anAsset.creationDate.value);
      
        NSDate *creationDate =(NSDate *)anAsset.creationDate.value;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];
        dayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:creationDate];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        timeString = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:creationDate];
```

I have tried to find the location key but with no luck.
Can someone show me how to do this or point me to a good tutorial and how to accomplish this.  I am using objective-c.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out.  I added these lines of code

```
PHAsset *someAsset = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset];
        NSLog(@"someAsset%@",someAsset.location);
        self.currentLocation = someAsset.location;
```

I will change my original post to reflect changes.